# Continually restating a job using JobExecutionListener

Tags: spring-batch

We need a job to run continuously without the need for an external scheduler.
I have extended **JobExecutionListener**, as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myJob")
private Job job;

private int counter = 0;

@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

   jobExecution.stop();

   JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
   JobParameter jobParameter = new JobParameter((new Integer(++counter)).toString());
   jobParameters.getParameters().put("counter", jobParameter);
   try {
      jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
   } 
   catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (JobRestartException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

When run, a JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException is thrown.

```
JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=0, version=0, Job=[myJob]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From official doc:

> The shutdown is not immediate, since there is no way to force
>   immediate shutdown, especially if the execution is currently in
>   developer code that the framework has no control over, such as a
>   business service. However, as soon as control is returned back to the
>   framework, it will set the status of the current StepExecution to
>   BatchStatus.STOPPED, save it, then do the same for the JobExecution
>   before finishing.

Maybe you can have a chance using a specialized JobLauncher that launch the job after previous job's thread termination or a custom TaskExecutor associated to JobLauncher.